# Problems centering div and auto expanding on top and bottom

Tags: html, css, center

I have a slight problem, I'd like the inner div to be bang on in the center of its outer div and also expand on the top aswell as the bottom if more text is added rather than just downwards as showing. I have highlighted where I want the div to be on the image in red and how I would like it to expand.

Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<div class="postlefttoright"><!--start of post-->

        <div class="featuredimageblog"><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/534/371" /></div>

        <div class="featuredexcon">

            <div class="featuredexconinner">

                <div class="featuredexcontent">

                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div><!--end of post-->
```

CSS

```
.postlefttoright {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width: 1067px;
    height:371px;
    margin-bottom:53px;
}

.featuredimageblog {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width: 534px;
    height:371px;}

.featuredexcon {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width: 533px;
    height:371px;}  

.featuredexconinner {
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 407px;
    height:371px;}      

.featuredexcontent {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    width: 407px;
    height:171px;}
```

Comment: Sooo... where is the highlight you were talking about?

Comment: It sounds like you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/v3EfS/1/

Comment: That works.. Thanks alot BuddhistBeast :)

Comment: Let me put it up as an answer really fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix to this would be to add a `display: table` and its correspondent `display:table-cell` which will ultimately work with `vertical-align:middle`. In order to do this, you would need to take out the following code:

```
.featuredexconinner {
position: relative;
margin:0 auto;
background:gray;
width: 407px;
height:auto;
}
```

Simply because you do not need to have a div within a div within a div (div-ception). Instead, you just need the following code:

```
.featuredexcon {
    display:table;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width: 533px;
    height:371px;
}
.featuredexcontent {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;    
    width: 407px;
    height:auto;
}
```

And that should fix your code, assuming you have taken out the appropriate HTML from the section I said to take out. A quick note as well, `position:absolute` mixed with `top:50%` will move your div and will prevent you from vertically aligning the div due to the absolute positioning.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v3EfS/1/)